# Amazon SNS Push - How do I define the push notification icon

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have googled the heck out of this one and searched the AWS docs, but still can't find the answer.

**Where do I define the push notification icon image for AWS SNS Service for GCM Android?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that works in PHP;

```
                'GCM' => json_encode(
                    [
                        'priority' => 'high', 
                        'data' => 
                            [
                                'message' => "Some message here",
                                'largeIcon' => 'ic_notification',
                                'smallIcon' => 'ic_foreground',
                                'color' => '#30AAFD',
                            ]
                    ])
```